# Get text nodes with their parent elements sequentially (harder than it seems)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, textnode

Consider the following markup:

```
<div>Hello, my <span>name</span> is John</div>
```

I need to get the text nodes and the elements containing them, sequentially, as in:

1: `"Hello, my "`, `<div>` (HTMLElement)

2: `"name"`, `<span>` (HTMLElement)

3: `" is John"`, `<div>` (HTMLElement)

This needs to be done in a way that allows me to get CSS style of HTMLElements later.

**What I already tried:**

```
$(foo).find('*').contents().filter(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim($this.text()).length > 0; 
});
```

This results in a non-sequential result set, as in:

1: `"Hello, my "`

2: `" is John"`

3: `"name"`

However, I can access their parent elements, so this does half of the job.

The main question, therefore, is: **how do I get text nodes in the same sequence they are in the document?**

Comment: do you need to know what their element is? would `innerText` not be sufficient

Comment: Yeah, I need to know the element so I can later style them.

Comment: Your problem is easily-enough answered with depth-first recursion. Basically, you set the current element, then you check its list of child nodes (`for loop`), in order. Notice I say nodes and not elements, checking each one by type. If it's a text-node, you've already got the parent (current element), and if it's a DOM element, then you pass it in as a parameter to the same function (recursion). The function continues depth-first (think about going inside the span, vs the rest outside) until a node has no children. I'd write it out, but I'm on a phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in Norguard’s comment, this can be solved by traversing the document tree:

```
function process(element) { 
  var children = element.childNodes; 
  for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) { 
    var child = children[i]; 
    if(child.nodeType === 3) { 
      if(child.data) { 
        processText(child.data, element); 
      } 
    } else { 
      process(child); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

You can then call this function, passing the desired element as parameter, provide that you have written your specific processing of the text nodes as a function `processText(text, parent)`.

Note: I’m assuming `childNodes` contains the children in the order in which they appear in the document source. This sounds very natural, but I am unable to find a requirement on this in specifications, oddly enough – perhaps it is taken as self-evident.

Comment: The [childNodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1451460987) object is a [NodeList](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177), which `provides the abstraction of an ordered collection of nodes`, where I think "order" can safely be assumed to mean "DOM order" (though perhaps the specification should state that explicitly somewhere, it uses the term quite often).

Comment: I've apparently achieved the same effect using `TreeWalker` (I strongly believe it works almost the same way).